# Перебор всех разбиений на группы

Tags: алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика

Нужно перебрать все возможные разбиения данного массива на группы. Две группы, состоящие из одних и тех же элементов, расположенных в разном порядке считаются различными.

Вот пример всех возможных вариантов разбиения для массива (1,2,3):

```
(1),(2),(3) 
(1),(2,3) 
(1,2),(3) 
(1,3),(2) 
(1),(3,2) 
(2,1),(3) 
(3,1),(2) 
(1,3,2)
(2,1,3)
(2,3,1)
(3,1,2)
(3,2,1)
```

Comment: А как же `(3,2,1)`? Ведь "_Две группы, состоящие из одних и тех же элементов, расположенных в разном порядке считаются различными._"

Comment: @DmitriySimushev - зачем Вы придираетесь? Человек дал Вам (нам) задание, даже отформатировал "все возможные варианты". Просто отвечайте, знаете или не знаете.

Comment: @Igor, я не придираюсь. Просто от того, является ли `(3,2,1)` допустимой группой (в дополнение к `(1,2,3)`) зависит правильное решение.

Comment: @danpetruk, а что вы уже сделали для решения проблемы? Что именно не получилось? (вот теперь я придираюсь)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev - Напротив, это-то как раз законный вопрос.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос предполагает выполнение задания за спрашивающего.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev извиняюсь, обновил вопрос

Comment: @Igor вообще обычно закрывают обычно тогда, когда просят написать готовый код. Я лишь спрашиваю о алгоритме

Comment: @danpetruk - Прекрасная лазейка! Какая разница - "дайте код", "дайте алгоритм".

Comment: @Igor вообще огромная. Можно написать в ответе нечто вроде "просортите все элементы и каждый второй поставьте как вес n-ого ребра графа, а потом найдите кратчайший путь Форд-Белманном", а можно написать в ответе готовые ~70 строк кода

Comment: могут ли элементы быть равными?

Comment: Порядок групп важен? Скажем, `(1,2),(3)` и `(3),(1,2)` – это два варианта, или один?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите получить ВСЕ варианты, то воспользуйтесь [этим](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G)

Пример использования:

```
var allValues = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
List<String> result = new List<String>();
var indices = Enumerable.Range(1, allValues.Count);
foreach (int lowerIndex in indices)
{
    var partVariations = new Facet.Combinatorics.Variations<String>(allValues, lowerIndex);
    result.AddRange(partVariations.Select(p => String.Join(" ", p)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все разбиения можно сформировать рекуррентным образом, по количеству элементов в группе.

```
Part(1) = (1);  
Part(1,2) = Part(1)(2) + Part(1)[2] = (1)(2)+(1,2)+(2,1);  
Part(1,2,3) = Part(1,2)(3) + Part(1,2)[3] = ((1)(2)+(1,2)+(2,1))(3)+((1)(2)+(1,2)+(2,1))[3],  
Part(1,2,3) = (1)(2)(3)+(1,2)(3)+(2,1)(3) + (1)[3](2)+(1)(2)[3] + (1,2)[3]+(2,1)[3],
Part(1,2,3) = (1)(2)(3)+(1,2)(3)+(2,1)(3) + (3,1)(2)+(1,3)(2) + (1)(3,2)+(1)(2,3) +
    + (3,1,2)+(1,3,2)+(1,2,3) + (3,2,1)+(2,3,1)+(2,1,3),...
```

Т.е.

```
Part(1,2,...,k) = Part(1,2,...,k-1)(k) + Part(1,2,...,k-1)[k],
```

где запись `Part(1,2,...,k-1)(k)` означает операцию дописывания одиночной группы (k) к каждой из групп разбиения `Part(1,2,...,k-1)`,
а запись `Part(1,2,...,k-1)[k]` - операцию формирования множества разбиений, полученного путём вставки элемента k в каждое разбиение из  `Part(1,2,...,k-1)` (т.е. в одну из групп на одно из возможных мест), выполненной всеми возможными способами.
При этом:

```
(P1+P2+...)(k) = P1(k) + P2(k) +...,
(P1+P2+...)[k]  = P1[k] + P2[k] +...,
((G1)(G2)...)(k) = (G1)(G2)...(k),
((G1)(G2)...(GN))[k] = (G1)[k](G2)...GN + (G1)(G2)[k]...GN + (G1)(G2)...GN[k],
(e1,e2,...eN)[k] = (k,e1,e2,...eN) + (e1,k,e2,...eN) + (e1,e2,...k,eN) + (e1,e2,...eN,k).
```

Сравнение `P(1,2,3)` с условием задачи показывает, что в условии пропущена группа `(1,2,3)`.

Если среди элементов встречаются одинаковые, потребуется дополнительная проверка на повторы.

Answer (score 0):

Проще взглянуть на задачу, если записывать группы, как строки – меньше запятых. Даны три элемента (одна группа): `a b c`. Разбиение на группы будем обозначать запятыми. Вот три группы: `a,b,c`.

Тогда все варианты разбиения этих элементов в данном порядке на группы – это все варианты двоичных чисел длиной, равной числу пробелов между элементами (в данном случае, 2).

"0" соответствует пробелу, "1" – запятая. Вот все варианты для такого порядка элементов:

```
a b c    (00 = 0) 
a b,c    (01 = 1)
a,b c    (10 = 2)
a,b,c    (11 = 3)
```

Теперь нужно получить все возможные порядки элементов, и для каждого применить этот "двоичный" перебор разбиений.

Слева направо брать очередную позицию и прокручивать все варианты – какой элемент может на ней стоять, с учётом уже “занятых" левее. Можно подойти рекурсивно. Напр. [реализация на JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871714/556876):

```
function permutator(inputArr) {
  var results = [];

  function permute(arr, memo) {
    var cur, memo = memo || [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      cur = arr.splice(i, 1);
      if (arr.length === 0) {
        results.push(memo.concat(cur));
      }
      permute(arr.slice(), memo.concat(cur));
      arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]);
    }

    return results;
  }

  return permute(inputArr);
}
```

И, если элементы могут повторяться, надо этот момент рассмотреть отдельно. Но в условиях вопроса пока об этом ничего не уточняли.

Ещё не подумал – важен ли порядок групп? Пока считаю разный порядок одних и тех же групп разными решениями: `a,b c` и `b c,a` – это два разных варианта.

Comment: У Вас повторяются разбиения на одну и две группы. Нелогично, если потом всё одно элементы переставлять. И надо бы показать, сколько, и каких разбиений получается для трёх элементов, а то их и правда трудновато сосчитать.